# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler doesn't seem to return values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a simple web app that returns a student's name when I type in their ID number. The app should call a google scripts function (`searchIDReturnName`) and then pass its return value to my `updateName` function back on the front end.

**Here is my Apps Script:**

```
var url ="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zGW23PVYvTsORRs0jrKNdHqb73arsRYxy22O45k60vQ/edit?usp=sharing";

function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}

function searchIDReturnName(idNumber)
{
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("StudentList");
  
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  
  var idNumberList = data.map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var names = data.map(function(r){return r[1];}); 
  var position = idNumberList.indexOf(idNumber); 
  
  if(position > -1)
  {
  return names[position];
  }
  else
  {
  return 'No student found';
  }
  
}
```

**And here is my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <label> ID Number: </label> <input type = "text" id = "studentID">
    <br>
    <label id = "nameLabel" > Name: </label> <label id = "studentName"> </label> 
    
    
    
    <script> 
    document.getElementById("studentID").addEventListener("input", searchStudent); 
    
    function searchStudent()
    {
      var idNumber = document.getElementById("studentID").value; 
      if(idNumber.length === 5)
      {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateName).searchIDReturnName(idNumber);
        document.getElementById("studentName").innerHTML = "If";
      }
      else
      {
      document.getElementById("studentName").innerHTML = "Running";
      }
    }
    
    function updateName(studentName)
    {
      document.getElementByID("studentName").innerHTML = studentName;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have verified that `searchIDReturnName` function actually finds the matching student in the spreadsheet, it just won't return that value.

Comment: *it just won't return that value to my web app.* What makes you think that?

Comment: To test this, I added code something like this to the updateName function: document.getElementByID("studentName").innerHTML = "I ran updateName".

Comment: Do you have an element with the `id` "studentName" in your code? If some of your functions does not run your should troubleshoot by implementing `concole.log()` (instead of appending to `innerHTML`) in each function to log important values. Also, go to `View-Executions` to spot errors.

Comment: And what happened? The flow: 1.client calls server  function `searchIDReturnName` 2. `searchIDReturnName` runs and returns value to client. 3.`updateName` is called on client  4.`label id = "studentName"` is updated with student name. Which of the above do you think is the problem? Upto step2 can be tested/ checked with server logs(view> executions will show if and when the function is called) . Step 3 can be tested with adding a `console.log("I was called")` inside `updateName` and checking Chrome/Firefox>devtools>console on  the browser.

Comment: A common error source from Apps Script side would be if e.g. the sheet has less than two rows.

Answer (score 0):

GS:

```
function searchIDReturnName(idNumber){
  var idNumber=idNumber||'10001';  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  var idNumberList = data.map(function(r){return r[0];});
  Logger.log(idNumberList);
  var names = data.map(function(r){return r[1];}); 
  Logger.log(names);
  var position = idNumberList.indexOf(idNumber); 
  Logger.log(position);
  if(position>-1) {
    Logger.log(names[position]);
    return names[position]; 
  }else{
    Logger.log('No Student Found');
    return 'No student found';
  }
}

function showMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah1"), "Test")
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <label> ID Number: </label> <input type="text" id="studentID" oninput="searchStudent();">
    <br>
    <label id="nameLabel"> Name: </label> <input type="text" id="studentName" />
    <script>         
    function searchStudent() {
      console.log('I am here');
      var idNumber = document.getElementById("studentID").value; 
      if(idNumber.length==5) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateName).searchIDReturnName(idNumber);
        document.getElementById("studentName").value = "If";
      }else{
      document.getElementById("studentName").value = "Running";
      }
    }
    
    function updateName(studentName){
      console.log(studentName);
      document.getElementById("studentName").value = studentName;
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including a **brief** explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.